# How to use custom ABSPATH in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, web

I have a requirement, where my content developers need to add a few custom `define()` in wp-config.php, which we cannot accommodate for them to do it independently. To get around this issue, I added this:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/wp-extra-config.php');
```

at the bottom of the wp-config.php, for them to put all the custom defines in there but looks like it's not working. if I move, e.g. `define('DB_NAME', 'myDB');` from wp-config.php to wp-extra-config.php, it works just fine. But, for example, in one of the theme's `functions.php`, they have something like this:

```
if( !defined('PROD') || !PROD ){
    add_action( 'wp', 'personal_message_when_logged_in' );
}
```

to force redirect to login-page and `define('PROD', true);` is required in wp-config.php to bypass that. But if I move that to wp-extra-config.php, it doesn't work at all - any idea what's going wrong or what am I missing? Or, is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance! Best!

Comment: Sorry for noise: Just figured out that you need to add that line before `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');` - otherwise it's not gonna work.